# How to set the data in AJAX success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax call that is returning me the data to be populated in a drop down list. Now, I need to be able to select a value which is returned and set the value of the drop down in the same function if possible. But by using `$("#idOfDropDown").val(data)`, it is not getting set i.e While I am submitting the data, in the database all the options that were returned and populated are getting submitted and not the selected option. So, How do I set the selected value only?

Here's my AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "/Controller/Action",
  data: {
    param: param,
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.Response == "Unsuccessful") {
      console.log("Unsuccessful");
    } else if (data.Response == "Successful" || data.Response == "ConditionallySuccessful") {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.ExteriorColor.Data.length; i++) {
        $("#Exterior_Color").append($("<option></option>").val(data.ExteriorColor.Data[i]).html(data.ExteriorColor.Data[i]));
        console.log(data.ExteriorColor.Data[i]);
      }
      var html = '<ul>'
      for (var i = 0; i < data.Options.length; i++) {
        html += '<li>' + data.Options[i] + '</li>';
      }
      html += '</ul>'
      $("#twoColumnOptions").append(html);
      $("#twoColumnOptions").data(html);
      $("#Options").val(data.Options); 
      $("#Exterior_Color").val(data.ExteriorColor.Data).change(); //Value to be changed
      if (data.ExteriorColor.isInstalled == true)
        $("#Exterior_Color").attr("disabled", true);

    }

  },
  error: function(result) {
    console.log("Error while fetching data");
  }
});
```

Comment: At first I didn't read your question correctly, I re edited, I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: If the value is not being set then `data.Options` doesn't match the option values. Provide a [mcve] including sample data and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trigger the change you made using `.trigger('change')` like:

```
$("#Options").val(data.Options).trigger('change');
//Or
$("#Options").val(data.Options).change();
```

Comment: Yes it helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's just one problem here. If there are validation issues and the form returns back then the selected value is lost

Comment: You're welcome, please update the code in the OP with the last version so I can check with you..

Comment: I'v updated my code.. There isn't much change except the drop down id has now changed. The enum value now gets stored properly but the problem is during validation issue the page gets returned to the form but the selected value in the drop down is lost..

Comment: Then you request reach the success callback not the error one, what mean also that the server-side response is `"Successful" OR "ConditionallySuccessful"` .. check the server-side returns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161438/discussion-between-del-monte-and-zakaria-acharki).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar in my solution and my code is like this, you need to set the value like this:

```
  success: function (response) {
                var array = response;
                if (array != '') {
                    for (i in array) {
                        $("#district").append("<option value='"+ 
                       array[i].Id + "'>" + array[i].DistrictName + "</option>");
                        }
                    }
                },
```